# Calculate X,Y Postion for Video Mosaic View

Tags: python

I am very bad at math and I am not able to resolve this by myself, sorry if I bother you.

Where I am stuck is to calculate each x,y position for each pane in the mosaic view.

Below my function with instructions, I tried quite often but I see I am to dump for this, maybe one of you could be so kind and write me the lines in the for loop.

```
def create_panes(rows=2, colums=2, height=640, width=480):
    "Create panes for camera mosaic/multi view"
    "Returns a combined string of each pane/sink"

    "Example: Rows: 2, Colums: 2, Height:640, Width:480"
    "---------------------------"
    "|      0     |     1      |"
    "|            |            |"
    "|            |            |"
    "|            |            |"
    "---------------------------"
    "|      2     |     3      |"
    "|            |            |"
    "|            |            |"
    "|            |            |"
    "---------------------------"
    "Result for positions should be:"
    "Pane/Sink 0: x=0, y=0"
    "Pane/Sink 1: x=640, y=0"
    "Pane/Sink 2: x=0, y=480"
    "Pane/Sink 3: x=640, y=480"

    "Function should return this string:"
    "sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_1::xpos=640 sink_1::ypos=0 sink_2::xpos=0 sink_2::ypos=480 sink_3::xpos=640 sink_3::ypos=480"

    pane_template = "sink_{idx}::xpos={xpos} sink_{idx}::ypos={ypos}"

    for col in range(colums):
        for row in range(rows):
            ...
´´´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

```
    pane_template = "sink_{idx}::xpos={xpos} sink_{idx}::ypos={ypos}"
    out = []
    for col in range(colums):
        for row in range(rows):
            out.append(pane_template.format(idx=col*2+row, xpos=row*height, ypos=col*width))
    return ' '.join(out)
```

You can try it out on sololearn: https://code.sololearn.com/chJP92wNNVsc

Comment: No probs. You can develop your skills using simple online tools like the one I have mentioned in my answer.